# php Cannot call the function for array_map

Tags: php

I am using php 5.2.10 i want to do the array_map on the array and i created a function for array mapping

```
function get_result(){
    $result = mysql_query("Select * from table");
    while($cr = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $b = array_map(`calc`,$cr);
        $rr_id = $cr['batch_id'].$cr['seq_id'];
  $mqrrid = '999'.$rr_id;
  $question_id = $cr['question_id'];
        foreach ($b as $k => $v){
            if(preg_match('{^Item \d+$}',$k)){
                $new_insert[] = array(
                    'r_id'=>$mqrrid,
                    'q_id' =>$q_id,
                    'c_id' =>$k,
                    'rank'=>$v
                );
            }
        }
    }
}   

function calc($n){
    foreach($n as $m=> &$x) {
        if (preg_match('{^Item \d+$}', $m)) {
            if($x == null){
                $x = $x;
            }else {
                $x = $x - 1;
            }
        }
    }   
    return $n;
}
```

I don't know why I cannot call the function `calc` in `array_map`.....I cannot figure out the reason.....
Can anyone help me ?

original array :( actually the output after the array_map(`calc`,$cr) are same as follow)

```
array(23) {
["batch_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["seq_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["question_id"]=>
string(4) "2086"
["Item 1"]=>
string(1) "1"
["Item 2"]=>
string(1) "2"
["Item 3"]=>
string(1) "3"
["Item 4"]=>
string(1) "4"
["Item 5"]=>
string(1) "5"
["Item 6"]=>
NULL
```

what i need is : (minus the value of Item 1 to 6 by 1, if its null just leave it ~)

```
array(23) {
["batch_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["seq_id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["q_id"]=>
string(4) "2086"
["Item 1"]=>
string(1) "0"
["Item 2"]=>
string(1) "1"
["Item 3"]=>
string(1) "2"
["Item 4"]=>
string(1) "3"
["Item 5"]=>
string(1) "4"
["Item 6"]=>
NULL
```

Finally, the result will become like this:(example of Item 1 and Item 6)

```
 array(4) {
["r_id"]=>
string(5) "99911"
["q_id"]=>
string(4) "2086"
["c_id"]=>
string(6) "Item 1"
["rank"]=>
string(1) "0"
}
array(4) {
["r_id"]=>
string(5) "99916"
["q_id"]=>
string(4) "2086"
["c_id"]=>
string(6) "Item 6"
["rank"]=>
string(4) NULL
}
```

Comment: What's here `array_map(\`calc\`,$cr)` ? `\`` <-

Comment: In `calc()` you're returning `$n` o_o ? Shouldn't you return `$x`? By the way this `$x = $x;` does not make sense ...

Comment: what is the output or error message of this code?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I want it return null , if $x is null , how to express it ?

Comment: @user2210819 `if($x == null){ return null;}else{ ...`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV no matter I return $n or $x still didnt change the value of $x

Comment: Fixed indent and `\`calc\``

Comment: @ianace no error code , but the if i print_r($b) still give me the original array , I dont think the function calc have been carried out

Comment: @user2210819 [Try this](http://codepad.org/KCrh19ux)...

Comment: @user2210819 please provide sample input data and output data and the actual erroneous output

Comment: @CertaiN what do you mean

Comment: @user2210819 I just edited your code to be clear

Comment: What do you want to do in this code?

Comment: Backticks are not valid, use **quotes**: `array_map('calc', ...)`!

Comment: I just edited my code and provide the array and show you what i want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to prepare the function for `array_map`.

```
function get_result($link_identifier = NULL) {
    $result = mysql_query('Select * from table', $link_identifier);
    $new = array();
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $r_id = '999' . $rows['batch_id'] . $rows['seq_id'];
        foreach ($rows as $k => $v) {
            if ($v !== null && preg_match('@^Item \\d+$@', $k)) {
                $v = (string)((int)$v + 1);
            }
            $new[] = array(
                'r_id' => $r_id,
                'q_id' => $rows['question_id'],
                'c_id' => $k,
                'rank' => $v,
            );
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Comment: It takes time to modify i will let you know if its work or not !

Comment: @^Item \\d+$@ is different from {^Item \d+$}?

Comment: As a delimiter, `{ }` and `@ @` have same meanings. I prefer `@ @` to `{ }` because `{` and `}` have **special meanings** . [PHP Manual]  http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php About `\\d` and `\d`, see these links: **[PHP]** http://ideone.com/FWzLF0 **[C]** http://ideone.com/qpSP2T Note: Most major languages behaves like C. **Only PHP can behave oddly** .

Comment: great !!!! thank you!!!!!! It works !! and I want to ask you one more question , what is the $link identifier used for?

Comment: `mysql_query` is the very strange type function compared to `fgets` , `fwrite` , `curl_setpot` and so on. These functions must receive **resources** as the first argument. However, `mysql_query` receives it as the second argument, moreover, **it can be omitted**. Being omitted, PHP automatically use the latest connection. I think very odd of this way. If I use this function, I'll be sure to send resources.

Comment: And instead of `mysql`, you should use `mysqli` : this has both **procedural functions** and **object-oriented classes and methods**. I recommend you the latter. See the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php ; Also you have a choice to use `PDO`. This works on various types of databases. This has a big advantage of portability. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I'm just a Japanese teen so there may have been some English grammatical errors, sorry xD

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave me a detail explaination that help me alot. You english is good ! btw, I am not a english speaker also :P. I am chinese xp

Answer (score 3):

`calc` should be global, otherwise it cannot be found. Also, you should pass a string (no ` but rather enclose in ' or ").

Additionally, in general (if you used PHP 5.3), it is better to pass a *function reference* to the array_map function, instead of a string:

```
$func = function calc() { ... }
array_map($func, $cr);
```

Comment: See this: `I am using php 5.2.10`. Closure is supported on PHP 5.3 or later.

Comment: @Willem Mulder
thank you for your response but i am using php 5.2.10

Comment: Yeah, so ensure that calc is global and that you use no backticks but proper quotes. Does that work?

Comment: show nothing when using proper quotes, but as what @CertaiN said may be i did have to prepare the function for array_map. If i prepared and use proper quotes, it may work. but it takes time for me to modify it.